# excel check caller cell on a formula

Tags: excel, vba, equation

I have something like

January - February ...

Whatever:

It is, each column is a month and then 1st row has the month name, 2nd row has the number of whatever attribute i want (I'm just putting an example). My idea is to put something like.. in each cell under the month: =cellSomething

and in cell something I should check from which cell I'm calling and then check the month (upper cell) and do something like =If(callerCell.upper.month < May) = 5 else 10

how could I check the caller cell or pass a cell or value to the function?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure I understand the requirement, but I would go with something like this:

Use dates rather than names for your column headers (you can then apply formulas to them and also use a custom number format to display the month name). So something like this is what you seem to be asking for:

```
A1: 01/01/2017
B1: =DATE(2017,MONTH(A1)+1,1)
    drag this across to L1
    format A1:L1 with a custom number format: mmmm

A2: =IF(MONTH(A1)<5,5,10)
    drag this across to L2
```

Answer (score 0):

We already know where the months are in the first row, so in **B1** enter:

```
=IF(COLUMN()<5,5,10)
```

and copy across.